# Setting a Custom Title to the NSOpenPanel Cancel Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have tried using this:

1) Create the file `NSOpenPanelExtension.h` that contains:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSOpenPanel (Extension)

- (void)setCancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)newTitle;

@end
```

2) Create the file `NSOpenPanelExtension.m` that contains:

```
#import "NSOpenPanelExtension.h"

@implementation NSOpenPanel (Extension)

- (void)setCancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
{
NSRect oldFrame = [_cancelButton frame];

[_cancelButton setTitle:newTitle];
[_cancelButton sizeToFit];

NSRect newFrame = [_cancelButton frame];
float delta = oldFrame.size.width - newFrame.size.width;

[_cancelButton setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(oldFrame.origin.x + delta,
oldFrame.origin.y)];
}

@end
```

3) Use it where you need it:

```
#import "NSOpenPanelExtension.h"
...
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];  
[panel setCancelButtonTitle:@"NO!"];
```

But when I `[panel setCancelButtonTitle:@"NO!"]` my `NSOpenPanel` crashes and this appears on my console (along with the usual errors and codes):

```
*** Assertion failure in -[NSRemoteOpenPanel forwardingTargetForSelector:], /SourceCache/RemoteViewServices/RemoteViewServices-80.5/NSRemoteSavePanel.m:1975
An uncaught exception was raised
sandboxed save/open panel presently acting unlike a panel
```

What's wrong? How can I change the cancel button title of a `NSOpenPanel`? Example code would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be connected with changes in NSOpenPanel mentioned in [App Sandbox Design Guide:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html)

> Certain NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel methods behave differently when
>   App Sandbox is enabled for your app:
>
> You cannot invoke the OK button using the ok: method.
>
> You cannot rewrite the user’s selection using the
>   panel:userEnteredFilename:confirmed: method from the
>   NSOpenSavePanelDelegate protocol.
>
> In addition, the effective, **runtime inheritance path** for the
>   NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel classes **is different** with App Sandbox...

Comment: so it's not possible to change the title?

Comment: okay, thank you. I'm just gonna let this topic active for 1 more day, maybe some1 has an idea on how to do it. Then i'll accept your answer!

Comment: Complementing my last comment: I'm pretty sure, that is impossible to set this title in sandboxed applications. I've read more about sandboxing since yesterday, and, in sandboxed applications, in the fact,  you don't open your NSOpenPanel, but you send a request to system module called PowerBox.